# How to generate the serial no in front of every row and how to save the multiple rows data

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a HTML form which in which there is a button which adds row. I want to generate a serial no in front of each row in SL No column. and how can I save this multiple row data along with the details at the top. I have tried it with FOR loop but I could not. I am new to this.

```
<table  class="table table-striped small-text" id="tb" >

<tr class="tr-header">

<h4 style="color:darkGreen;" ><u>SAMPLE INFORMATION</u></h4> 
<th class= "col-md-1" align="centre">Sl.No.</th>
<th class= "col-md-2" align="centre">TYPE OF SAMPLE</th>
<th  class= "col-md-2" align="centre">Sample Location</th>
<th class= "col-md-6" align="centre"> Remarks</th>
<th><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore" title="Add More Sample"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th>
<tr>
<td><input type="text"  value= "1"   class="form-control" ></td> 
<td><select  type="text" name="type" class="form-control">
  <option value="SELECT TYPE">SELECT TYPE</option>
   <option value="BONE">BONE</option>
   <option value="CARBONATE">CARBONATE</option>

</select></td>

<td><input type="text" name="samplelocation" class="form-control" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="remarks" class="form-control"></td>
<td><a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-info"  align="middle" >Add </button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#addMore').on('click', function() {
              var data = $("#tb tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tb");
              data.find("input").val('');

     });
     $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
         var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            if(trIndex>1) {
             $(this).closest("tr").remove();
           } else {
             alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");
           }
      });
}); 

</script>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
     <!-- CONTENT-WRAPPER SECTION END-->
  <?php include('includes/footer.php');?>
      <!-- FOOTER SECTION END-->
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES PLACED AT THE BOTTOM TO REDUCE THE LOADING TIME  -->
    <!-- CORE JQUERY  -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS  -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS  -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by serial number? What/how would you expect it to be generated? Do you mean a number per row (1,2,3 etc...)?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Please explain what exactly you _mean_ by “serial number” (just a _counter_, or anything that follows a specific format?). Please _show_ what you tried (and explain your reasoning, and what the problem was with it.)

Comment: Ya It is number per row and to be displayed in the first column of each row in my givemn form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for generating a serial number part u can use this in php:

```
$sn1 = uniqid();
$sn2 = uniqid();
$sn3 = uniqid();
```

it creates a unique id for every mentioned variable